# Typescript: Not able to import object from another file

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

This seems like a very weird problem but for some reason I am not able to import a const declared in one file into another file. On importing the const I'm getting a TS error stating `Module '"../resources/dummy_container"' has no exported member 'dummy_container_responses'.`

Here are the code snippets.

```
   export const dummy_container_resoponses = [
    {
      "Id": "8dfafdbc3a40",
      "Names": [
        "/boring_feynman"
      ],
      "Image": "ubuntu:latest",
      "ImageID": "d74508fb6632491cea586a1fd7d748dfc5274cd6fdfedee309ecdcbc2bf5cb82",
      "Command": "echo 1",
      "Created": 1367854155,
    }
```

`import { dummy_container_responses } from '../resources/dummy_container';`

The path to file also seems to be correct.

[image: File path]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace the import path below mentioned,

`import { dummy_container_responses } from '../resources/dummy_container';`
with

`import { dummy_container_responses } from ../resources/dummy_container_responses';`

because I believe the code snippet you provided belongs to `dummy_container_responses.ts` file.

Comment: Happy to know it helps.